# Contact people who've purchased my Android app

Tags: android, google-play, android-pay

So, I may have done something very stupid. I uploaded a free version of my module to the Xposed repository, and a donate version to Google Play. Now, I want to add a feature or two to the Play Version, but not to the Xposed version - except they both have the same package name.

So, what I thought was, I'd remove the app from Play, and upload a completely new one with the additional features. But there's around 20 people who've already bought my app, and I really don't want them to have to be inconvenienced at all. How do I send them an email explaining this to them and giving them the link to the new app, if at all possible?

If not - do any of you have any suggestions? This is a frightfully embarrassing goof-up I've made. Thank you! :)

Comment: What stops you from updating the APK on play store but not in the xposed repository?

Comment: You could keep the package name the same and only upload the update to GP. The people who have downloaded from other sources will be unable to get the update.

Comment: @hypd09, @Code-Apprentice - there's an update I want to push to the repository as well, and I'll want to push continuous updates to both; just larger updates to the donate version. I've thought of a tentative fix - set the `versionCode` of the donate version to, say, 100, and the updates as 101, 102, and so on, while the free version could be 1, 2, and 3. That way, they both get their own separate update chains. Is this a plausible fix, do you think?

Comment: I am not understanding what the issue is.. treat them as separate apps or say different flavors of same app.
You can keep the version numbers same or different, it doesn't matter as user would only have one installed application on their device. But preferably you should keep the version numbers for repo builds smaller to avoid chance of users replacing the paid application with that.